# CRM PDF Creator / Generator 2015 online

Tags: pdf-generation, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I recently had an interesting situation with one of our clients who wanted to send out pdf invoice from CRM 2015 online. I did some research, one approach seems to be doable, use javascript to download a copy of SSRS report and save as pdf, but this is a hack to the report viewer, and it is not supported by Microsoft. Also, the client want to display customer’s signature on the pdf. I found another solution to convert SSRS into PDF using workflow custom code activity, but it only works with on premise CRM, not CRM online. The client is using MS CRM online 2015. The solution needs be able to run in isolated sandbox. Is it possible?

Comment: I find out that I can use a plugin to convert the html to pdf by a third part pdf tool. The first step is create a pdfcreate request entity and enclose all logic of creating the pdf into the entity precreate plugin. I will post my source code somewhere in the future. let me know if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, create html in the plugin first, then call pdfcreator tool. the tool can create a pdf and attach the pdf back to entity record or an email message. Please let me know if you like this tool. right now it's free to use with limitation. the solution file is exported from crm 2015 online update 1. If you need a solution for different version of CRM, please let me know.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1009639/Create-Generate-PDF-from-CRM-with-JScript-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can either write custom code or (probably the better option for your client) is to look at [XperiDo for Dynamics CRM](http://xperido.com/products/xperido-microsoft-dynamics-crm).

Comment: This is a little bit overkill for my situation. thanks though.